# Mapview in separate fragment android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to have a mapview like this suppose my main activity is like this 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzADf.jpg]
Here my main activity holds the instance of mapview in main activity and then when I click on it ,then a new activity should be opened with the map activity in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the supportMapFragment in your xml file and get the reference of mapFragment into your MainFragment. The below code explains, How I accomplished the MapView inside Fragment. Write the below XML code in the mapView.xml and then Use the Fragment OnCreateView to get references.

`<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/mainMap"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                     />`

```
public class MapInFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private View rootView;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapView, container, false);





    try{
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainMap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapInFragment.this);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    try {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng croplatlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(croplatlng).title(crop + "Field"));

        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(croplatlng,16));

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(croplatlng , 16);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(""));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation ));
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate,2000,null);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void onDestroyView()
{
    try {
        Fragment fragment = (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainMap));
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
Add Mapview on your main activity.

**Step 2:**
Add OnClickListener on MapView

```
mMapView.getMap().setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0)
                    {
                        //Open New Activity
                    }
                });
```

**Step 3:**
Open New Activiy to show your map.

Hope you will find this answer usefull.
Happy Coading