# How do you use a Google MapView inside of a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mapview, google-maps-api-2

## Desired Behavior

In case it affects any answers or suggestions, what I would like to ultimately see in this app is a navigation UI where one of the `Fragment` is a map.  I used a template to start with a navigation UI, which gave me several `Fragment`s, one for each tab.  Currently, I'm trying to use the Google API to put a `MapView` inside of one of those `Fragment`s.

## Current Behavior

Generally, this isn't working (obviously).  I have everything up and running, but when I pull up the tab with the map in it, the map is blank.  Nothing crashes, and no errors are output:

```
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 201516040
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
```

## Other Details/Troubleshooting

I know that my API key works because I have another app in which the maps work as expected.  I doubt I need a second API key, but I looked anyway and since it wasn't overly obvious how to create a second API key, I think that hunch is correct.  Most of the code I'm using was copied from that working example; the primary difference is that other example uses a `SupportMapFragment` and it has a `class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity`.  Here, since I don't really want to deal with nesting fragments, I'm trying to use a `MapView` inside that fragment.

What bits of my code that weren't copied largely came from online sources.  None of what I've tried has produced better results.

[MapView inside fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270958/mapview-inside-fragment) is answering a different problem

[Creating google maps v2 in a fragment using Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985046/creating-google-maps-v2-in-a-fragment-using-navigation-drawer) contains only things I already have

[android MapView in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174527/android-mapview-in-fragment) gave me the idea to use `MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());` but that didn't help

[Mapview in separate fragment android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585989/mapview-in-separate-fragment-android) has nothing new

[how do i solve integrating google map in fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442253/how-do-i-solve-integrating-google-map-in-fragment-in-android) uses a `Fragment` not a `MapView`

I also know that `onMapReady` is being called.  Inside of that, I move the camera and that subsequently calls `onCameraMoveStarted`.  However, it does not enter `onCameraMove` or `onCameraIdle`.

## Code

This is the code as it is, which uses some of the ideas from the above links.  I tried to cut out anything that's unrelated (other fragments, etc)

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.retailtherapy">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### mobile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_map">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_map"
        android:name="com.example.retailtherapy.ui.map.MapFragment"
        android:label="Map"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

</navigation>
```

#### fragment_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.map.MapFragment" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    /*************************************************************************
     *
     * M E M B E R S
     *
     */

    // Location manager for getting current location
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;

    // The map object for reference for ease of adding points and such
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap = null;
    private MapView mMapView = null;

    // The camera position tells us where the view is on the map
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition = Constants.GetDefaultCameraPosition();

    // Current latitude and longitude of user
    private LatLng mCurrentLatLong = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

    // These are flags that allow us to selectively not move the camera and
    // instead wait for idle so the movement isn't jerky
    private boolean mCameraMoving = false;
    private boolean mPendingUpdate = false;

    /*************************************************************************
     *
     * F R A G M E N T
     *
     */

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        // The google map...
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        mMapView = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.googleMap);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        // The required permissions...
        final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
        };
        requestPermissions(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, 0);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() throws SecurityException {
        super.onStart();

        // Location manager for getting info current location
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    /*************************************************************************
     *
     * G O O G L E   M A P S
     *
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        // Assuming if here that we have permissions okay.  Dangerous sure
        // but I'm lazy...
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Store the location of the camera for UI purposes so we can go
        // back to where we were
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                mCameraPosition = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition();
            }
        });
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
                mCameraMoving = true;
            }
        });
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                mCameraMoving = false;
                if (mPendingUpdate) {
                    centerCameraOnLocation(false);
                }
            }
        });

        // Start with user centered in view
        centerCameraOnLocation(true);
    }

    /*************************************************************************
     *
     * L O C A T I O N
     *
     */

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Store the current location so if we start auto-center but aren't
        // already, we know where to pan to
        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (!newLatLng.equals(mCurrentLatLong)) {
            mCurrentLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            centerCameraOnLocation(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    /*************************************************************************
     *
     * M A P   C A M E R A
     *
     */

    /*
     * Updates the camera position based on current state.  If the camera is
     * already moving, then wait.
     */
    private void centerCameraOnLocation(boolean animate) {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mCameraMoving) {
            mPendingUpdate = true;
            return;
        }

        // Get the CameraPosition to update to based on whether we are auto
        // centering or not.
        if (mCameraPosition == null) {
            mCameraPosition = Constants.GetDefaultCameraPosition();
        }

        // If this is the same as it was before, then don't reset it
        if (mCameraPosition.equals(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition())) {
            return;
        }

        // Make the update so we can move the camera
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition);

        // Move the camera with or without animation.  The time we don't want
        // animation is when we're setting the position initially
        if (animate) {
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
        else {
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
        mPendingUpdate = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY I found the answer in a comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464293/3038157.

Basically, it seems there was something stale.  Without changing any code, I uninstalled the app, cleaned the build, rebuilt, and voila it worked.

Comment: In my case, its those mapview's lifecycle methods I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

You must forward all the life cycle methods from the Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class.
View this [official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/MapView?hl=en)
or [example code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/main/ApiDemos/java/app/src/gms/java/com/example/mapdemo/RawMapViewDemoActivity.java)

```
 // *** IMPORTANT ***
 // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
 // objects or sub-Bundles.
```